# Proving that $\nu^+(E) = \sup\{\nu(C) :C \in \mathcal{A}, C\subset E\}$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

If $\nu$ is a signed measure on $(X, \mathcal{A})$, how to prove that $\nu^+(E) = \sup\{\nu(C) :C \in \mathcal{A}, C\subset E\}$? I am thinking of using the Hahn decomposition, so $\nu^+(E) = \nu(E \cap P)$. But I am not sure how to proceed.

Comment: You might want to clarify your notation.

Answer (score 0):

Since $E\cap P\subset E$,
$$
\nu^+(E)=\nu(E\cap P)\le \sup\{\nu(C): C\in \mathcal{A},C\subset E\}.
$$
Also for $C\subset E$, $\nu(C)= \nu^+(C)-\nu^-(C)\le \nu^+(E)$. Thus,
$$
\sup\{\nu(C): C\in \mathcal{A},C\subset E\}\le \nu^+(E).
$$

Comment: Thanks very much ! I just can't see how you conclude that 
 ν(E)=ν(E∩P)≤sup{ν(C):C∈A,C⊂E}, is it that obvious ?

Comment: The supremum is taken over a family of sets that contains $E\cap P$ and so it is at least $\nu(E\cap P)$.

Comment: Oh I see, I don't know how I didn't realize that. Thanks !